# Segmentation fault at global variable initialization in shared library

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, global-variables, shared-libraries

I have a shared library that contains global variable

```
    int ***carg;
```

This variable is initialized at function

```
    __attribute__((constructor)) void init(void) {
        carg = generator->get_carg();
    }
```

where

```
    int*** get_carg();
```

just returns preinitialized carg array.

If this library is loading there is segmentation fault

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x00007fffebe05fea in init () at /path/to/project/main.cpp:814

In this frame

```
    (gdb) print carg
    $1 = (int ***) 0x0
    (gdb) call generator->get_carg()
    $2 = (int ***) 0xf12410
```

Why this assignment (one pointer is assigned to other pointer) is the cause of segmentation fault? And how can I initialize this variable?

UPD: I still don't know answer, but when **carg** variable was renamed, there is no errors. I thought that there is one more variable with this name, but that's not so.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the generator variable is not initialized yet and doesn't point to a valid object.

Calling get_cargs() then results in a segmentation fault.

Comment: No, get_cargs() it's ok, because in this frame 
`(gdb) print generator->get_carg()[0][0][0]`
is working.
It's surprisingly for me that I can
`(gdb) call generator->get_cargs()`
`(gdb) $5`
`(gdb) set carg = $`
and there is no errors